# Relation between cointegration space and presence of linear trend

Tags: time-series, cointegration, trend, vector-error-correction-model

I am reading Pfaff "Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R" (2008). On page 130, section 8.1.2 "Determining the Cointegration Rank" they start by determining cointegration rank. Because **inferences on cointegration space spanned by its vectors are dependent on whether or not linear trends exist in the data**, they argue by ocular econometrics and logical reasoning that the price series have a linear trend that is consistent with the steady-state assumption of constant nominal price growth as implied by economic theory, and therefore the vector $\mu$ can be estimated without imposing any restrictions.

What is the relation between "cointegration space spanned by the eigenvectors" and "the existence of linear trend in the data"?

The cases are:

1. no linear trend in the data;
2. linear trend in the data.

What is the result of these two cases on "cointegration space spanned by the eigenvectors"?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Assume Yt is a vector  of variables, i.e, Yt=(Y1t,Y2t,...,Y5t), t=1,...,p. Pfaff: "...Because inferences on the cointegration space spanned by its vectors are dependent on whether or not linear trends exist in the data,..."

Comment: It could probably make sense to cite the passage you are having trouble with. Perhaps it will reflect the actual problem best.

Comment: PFAFF 2008 "Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R". Page 130. 8.1.2 Determining the Cointegration Rank
J-J start by determining cointegration rank. Because
inferences on cointegration space spanned by its vectors are dependent on whether or not linear trends exist in the data, they argued by ocular econometrics and logical reasoning that the price series have a linear trend that is consistent with the steady-state assumption of constant nominal price growth as implied by economic theory, and therefore the vector μ can be estimated without imposing any restrictions.

Comment: Thx a lot Hardy for your nice editing. The reason I shorthened that much at the beginning is that I did not want to direct the users in advance in any direction, and that's why, I removed the context to that degree. This made it very elaborate as you implied.

Comment: I am not completely sure which way is better, so feel free to undo the edits if you later change your mind. I just found your question a bit unclear and lacking context, but that is only my perception.

Comment: Your edit looks smarter definitely. Now, I am trying to follow "JOHANSEN 1990 Maximum likelihood estimation and inference on cointegration". It seems the paper answers my questions. Once I got a clear picture, I'll present it as a solution.